# Сервис не запускается после включения компьютера

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-service

Я создал Windows Service Application, с автоматическим запуском.

```
public ServiceInstaller()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller {Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem};
  var serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller
  {
     ServiceName = "TestService",
     Description = "Test",
     StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic
  };
  Installers.Add(processInstaller);
  Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
}
```

Суть сервиса в следующем: в методе `OnStart` запускается `Nancy` сервер, который должен обрабатывать запросы.

```
public partial class NancyService : ServiceBase
{
  private NancyHost _nancyHost;
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
     EventLog.WriteEntry("NancyService->OnStart", EventLogEntryType.Information, 1);
     _nancyHost = NancyModuleStarter.Start("http://localhost", 4321);
  }
}
```

Сервис не всегда запускается после отключения и включения компьютера (чаще всего воспроизводится, если перед выключением компьютера сервис был отключен)
Заглянул в логи `Event Viewer`, никаких ошибок связанное с нашим сервисом я не нашел.
Добавил `EventLog.WriteEntry` в метод OnStart (чтобы понять вызывается ли метод OnStart после включения компьютера). Оказалось, что в `Event Viewer`логи не записываются даже если сервис был запущен
автоматически. Т.е. если сервис запускаю вручную (`Service manager`, кнопка `Start Service`), то лог записывается в `Event Viewer`, если автоматически то не записывается.

[здесь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuWnSSPXVpwVg_MWVLNPh_tDXfIunwok/view?usp=sharing) проект. Если запустить сервис, затем сделать запрос http://localhost:4321/settings, то получим ответ `Hello world`.

Скажите пожалуйста,

1. Почему не вызывается метод `OnStart`, если сервис был запущен автоматически после включения компьютера?
2. Как могу понять почему не запустился сервис автоматически? Имеются какие-либо методы отладки?

Comment: Когда Вы запускаете сервер вручную проверьте в Task Manager под каким пользователем бежит Ваш сервис.  Скорее всего в автоматическом старте он бежит под пользователем(local system etc) у которого недостаточно прав. Посмотрите в EventViewer ошибки которые подходят по времени но не связаны с сервисом.

Comment: @WinnerIT  В обоих случаях имя пользователя `SYSTEM`